# Using a lookup table with openCV and NumPy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, pixel

I'm trying to use NumPy and CV2 by doing pixel math on an array of pixels then using a lookup table and replacing that pixel with the lookup table's value.

This works but it is too slow,

```
image = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Event38\\Desktop\\IMG_2231.JPG')
height, width, depth = image.shape
image = image.astype('float')

B = image[:, :, 0]
G = image[:, :, 1]
R = image[:, :, 2]

num = ((R+G)-(2*B))
den = ((R+G)+(2*B))
NDVI = ((num/den)*127.5) + 127.5

print NDVI[0,0] # print array NDVI spot 0,0 value
print r[NDVI[0,0]][0] # looks up NDVI's spot 0,0 in LUT

for i in range(0, height):  
    for j in range (0, width):
        image.itemset((i,j,0),r[NDVI[i,j]][3])
        image.itemset((i,j,1),r[NDVI[i,j]][2])
        image.itemset((i,j,2),r[NDVI[i,j]][1])
#image = np.where(den == 0,1, NDVI).clip(0.0, 255.0)
```

Any advice on how to make the for-loop part of the code work faster would be great, I know there's some way to eliminate it. Thanks!

Comment: It all depends on what `r` is.

Answer (score 2):

You can try OpenCV's Look Up Table to apply a LUT in one shot.  Here is the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=lut#lut)

**C++**

```
void LUT(InputArray src, InputArray lut, OutputArray dst, int interpolation=0 )
```

**Python**

```
cv2.LUT(src, lut[, dst[, interpolation]]) → dst
```