# Performance for pixel point transformations

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, opencv, image-processing

So I'm using numpy and OpenCV to process a few videos. The problem I'm having is using a lookup table to do a point transformation on the pixel values:

```
def sig(x,factor):
    if x == 255:
        return 255
    elif x!=0:
        return int(255*(1- 1/(1+(255/x -1)**(-factor))))
    else:
        return 0

def Constrast(img):
    global LUT
    for x in range(len(img)):
        for y in range(len(img[0])):
            img[x,y] = LUT[img[x,y]]
    return img

 def Enhance(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #Some other functions here
    img = Constrast(img) # This one thing takes 0.3 seconds
    #Do more stuff here

factor = .8
LUT = []
for i in range(256):
    LUT.append(sig(i,factor))
Enhance(img) # Enhancing a greyscale image
```

The reason I am using a global variable is because my contrast function is nested in other functions. I have tested using `LUT` as an argument to these functions and it turned out slower. I have used numpy arrays, dictionaries, arrays from the array module and lists, with the latter being the fastest. So far I'm managing 0.3s on every image. Is there an obvious way of making the process of looping through pixels  quicker?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not loop over the pixels. Use OpenCV functionality to perform the transformation in one call. As a general rule-of-thumb, always try to avoid looping over pixels with OpenCV, and with Python, and especially with both.

An example how your code could be adapted:

```
def Constrat(img):
    global LUT
    img = cv2.LUT(img, LUT)
    return img
```

See the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29547576/21974) and [relevant documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab55b8d062b7f5587720ede032d34156f).

Comment: This has led to: ```TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'lut'```. Any suggestions?

Comment: Needed to check my dtypes, all worked out. Thanks massive increase in performance, why is looping particularly slow in this case?

Comment: @Jkind9 your loop uses code in Python. Functions in OpenCV/numpy use code in C/C++/Fortran which work faster. Some modules may use even GPU: [NumPy GPU acceleration](https://stsievert.com/blog/2016/07/01/numpy-gpu/)

Comment: Apart from what @furas said, many operations in OpenCV are implemented with further optimizations, e.g. utilizing vector instructions to update several pixels in one instruction.